# Gauge freedom in (3+1) general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gauge-theory, gauge, adm-formalism

In the ADM formalism of general relativity, in which one rewrites Einstein's field equations in terms of evolution and constraint eqautions of the $3$-metric and the extrinsic curvature, after fixing a lapse $N$ and shift $X$, is there still some remaining gauge freedom?

I understand that the lapse function and shift vector determine the foliation and act as some kind of Lagrange multipliers in the equations. Furthermore, the choice of lapse and shift is usually understood to be a choice of gauge. But after fixing $N$ and $X$, is the gauge fixing complete, or are the ADM equations still subject to some residual gauge freedom?

Comment: Refer to chapter 9 from [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0703035.pdf)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on that? So, if I understand correctly, the choice of lapse corresponds to the gauge choice in time direction and the shift can be used to fix the gauge on the 3 surface partially, but it seems that there is still some remaining freedom in choosing the coordinates on the 3 surface. Is that correct?

Comment: What about the other formulations discussed in these notes, like Einstein-Christoffel and BSSN? Is there the gauge completeles fixed?

Comment: Yes you are correct. Choice of $(N,X)$ fixes foliation $\Sigma_t$ and coordinates $x^i$ (partially) respectively. There are still ways to completely fix the spatial coordinates (see section 9.4). Once they are completely fixed, we can then talk about evolution schemes like Einstein-Christoffel and BSSN, which describes ways to integrate Einstein's equations. These evolution schemes are independent of gauge fixing conditions.

Comment: Okay I see. Thanks a lot! Just for my unterstanding: So "evolution scheme" means that I have a well-defined and completely fixed system, in which I get a unique solution for some fixed initial data?

Comment: Yes, these criterions should be more than sufficient. However, its not necessary to have a completely fixed coordinate system to discuss the evolution schemes (e.g. for BSSN scheme, see the discussion towards the end of section 10.4.3). One can allow for any coordinate system, but that could give rise to additional constraint equations

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks for clarification!